# How to install drivers for dell?

Tags: 16.10, ubuntu-drivers

I`m using Dell Inspiron 5520,i went to Dell`s official site,and there is only a list of available drivers for Windows operating systems.
Is there a way to check for and install the available versions of drivers for this model(or any other).
Using 16.10 Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: What drivers you need? Graphics, Network, etc.

Comment: I wanted to check for all of them,graphics network audio etc...

Comment: most of the drivers are fairly generic and included in what you have in Ubuntu already.  The primary exception in my experience (inspiron 15R 5521) is that the graphics drivers may need to be improved slightly.  I use drivers from (oibaf)[https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers] but with the current version of Ubuntu, this may be unneccesary

Comment: Audio and network device are working?

Comment: Poke..any update on this?